Segmentation fault occur in function when passing char* instead of char[] during equation. How can I get access to char* literal? (avoiding read-only)
Here's function code:
void TrimRight(char* s)
{
    if(!*s) return;

    char* end = 0;

    for(char c; c = *s; s++)
    {
        if(c == ' ') { if(end == 0) end = s; }
        else end = 0;
    }

    if(end) 
        *end = '\0'; // segmentation fault when char* is char* and not through char[]
}

I knew that stuff about stacks, segments etc...
But even assembly code of these things is the same:
char* text = "I'm a text";

int main()
{
    TrimRight(text);
    return 0;
}

.LC0:
        .string "I'm a text"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    TrimRight(char*)
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret

and
char text[] = "I'm a text";

int main()
{
    char* ptr = text;
    TrimRight(ptr);
    return 0;
}

text:
        .string "I'm a text"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:text
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    TrimRight(char*)
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret

I still don't understand what the difference is in the transfer.
Before that, I suspected that perhaps the assembler does not parse the already passed pointer well, as if it were implemented by the first option. However, this is complete nonsense! The address value will not go anywhere, being passed as a parameter.
So how to resovle it?

Alright. String literals, read-only memory it's all good. But is there any possibility to get access by this way?

@Gauliux You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

String literals are read only, char arrays are not

Also be very very clear about weather this question is for C++ or C (and your code is "C"). In C++ you should use std::string_view (or const std::string_view and then the difference will be much more clear and explicit)

@VladfromMoscow But... assemly is the same. No difference. I actually just try to change one thing in memory... Is there really not a single option for me to change such a piece of memory? And everything is tied only to the logic of C, regardless of how the generated code interprets it?

@Gauliux Logic  can be the same but addresses of strings are different.

Pretty sure you omitted important detail from the assembly listing. One of those should be in a read-only section (probably .rodata) while the other in a writable one (.data).

@Gauliux And your function has a logical error. Consider for example strings that contain only one or two spaces. In such a case the initial space will be kept in the string. And you should take into account also the tab character '\t'.

@VladfromMoscow No, it's not. It works correct. And yes, only space check I need, no other things.

@Gauliux Bear in mind that though in C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays you should always declare pointers to string literals with qualifier const. If you would do that const char* text = "I'm a text"; you had a reasonable compiler error.:)

@Gauliux It does not work correctly. One more consider strings "#" and "##" where # stands for a space. In the both cases you will get a string that contains one space.

@VladfromMoscow Just checked, works correct, I actually have no problem with it (GCC -O2). And, there's really no any possible to change access, even if compiled code is the same? I understand the difference, but is there any real possibility to get access or tottaly not?

@Gauliux I am sorry. You are right about your logic of the code.

Does this answer your question? Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a "char *s" initialized with a string literal, but not "char s[]"?

Character string literals are read-only. Full stop, end of story. No ifs or buts.
